# Purpose of classical approach | Relationship to object state

Tags: javascript

There is a library written purely using objects literals to group similar items.  This is some what related to having public static classes.  For example

```
var public_statics = {
    var1 : 'hello',
    func1 : function(){//stuff}
};
```

I see that people write OO ( or similar) JavaScript by emulating classes or simply using new on JavaScript function objects.

In web(I've heard this on SO and experienced it), it seems there is not much state.   What I mean by this, is you never seem to have 2 different objects from the same "class".

For example I have a UserNew model "class" in which it is only possible to have one model at any given time.  In fact all of my models are this way, there is only one instance at any given time.

Are there any examples of state-full applications ( where you instantiate multiple objects )?

Am I perhaps building out this library wrong if all the models are collections of public statics using object literals?

I can post any code that might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. I can think of two advantages to this approach.

1) Just in case you do have situations where you need multiple objects: perhaps a mail app could represent each user visible on a screen as user objects, or each mail as mail objects.

2) Namespace differentiation - a nice way to organise and group functions and data into a related namespace.